# Is it OK to un-subscribe and re-subscribe all my @Lexical/react command listeners on every render?

Tags: reactjs, lexicaljs

In `@lexical/react`, is there a substantial penalty (performance or other) for registering editor commands in a `useEffect` with no dependency array?

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = editor.registerCommand(
    KEY_ENTER_COMMAND,
    event => { /* ... */ },
    COMMAND_PRIORITY_HIGH
  )

  return unsubscribe
})
```

Is this internally demanding for `Lexical`, or is it merely a question of calling an extra simple function? Or are there maybe some other downsides to this approach?

Comment: I'm asking, because I would find it very convenient if I could make a `useCommandSubscription` hook that would subscribe a callback for me, without having to stabilize the callback's reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's fairly cheap, behind the scenes we just add/delete from a Map and a Set. But it's cheaper if you have to do none of this.

`useCommandSubscription` is an OK abstraction, some (untested) code:

```
function useCommandSubscription<T>(command: LexicalCommand<T>, fn: CommandListener<T>, priority: CommandListenerPriority): void {
  const [editor] = useLexicalComposerContext();
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    return editor.registerCommand(command, fn, priority);
  }, [editor]);
}
useCommandSubscription(FOO_COMMAND, () => { ... }, priority);
```

But note how you can further optimize what we provide out of the box:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // You can return immediately, no need to store the cleanup function in a variable
  return editor.registerCommand(...);
}, [editor]);
```

A common use case is that you listen to multiple commands/updates at once, you can leverage `mergeRegister` (from @lexical/utils):

```
useEffect(() => {
  return mergeRegister(
    editor.registerCommand(..),
    editor.registerCommand(..),
    editor.registerUpdateListener(..),
}, [editor]);
```

Side note: Beware when listening to the key enter command. Android works with composition and will not trigger a key enter event. Depending on your use case you may want to explore `INSERT_LINE_BREAK_COMMAND`, `INSERT_PARAGRAPH_COMMAND`, transforms based on `LineBreakNode` or `ParagraphNode` or mutation listeners based on these two nodes.

Comment: My idea of re-subscribing commands on every render seemed to work out initially, but started being very buggy when I put in a bunch of plugins - I haven't diagnosed it exactly, but it seems to be related to command handlers being un-subscribed and re-subscribed before they get to handle a command, when a different handler of the same command re-renders their subscription before they get their turn - is this possible?

Comment: For example I have handler `H1` with high priority and `H2` with medium priority, and they both listen to command `C`. But handler `H1` results in a state change, which re-invokes the `useEffect` which registers (and un-registers) command `H2`, before `H2` gets to react to `C`.  Or is `Lexical` specifically designed in such a way that no `React` re-renders can happen before all command listeners are done?

Comment: Using proper dependency lists in my `useLayoutEffect`s (as opposed to no second argument) managed to solve all of those bugs.